# jquery initialized console log

Tags: jquery

How can I print something, eg.

```
console.log "inited"
```

when jquery has downloaded and initialized itself on a webpage.

So far I have

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Also its `console.log("inited")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function check load (Handler for .ready() ):

```js
$(function() {
   console.log( "Jquery Initilised.The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated." );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```